# Is it OK to answer the Stack Overflow questions using ChatGPT AI + own logic?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I'm trying to answer the critical Stack Overflow questions using ChatGPT AI and also including my own logic by modification on it. Is it Ok to do that? If not, then why? Please clarify!

I'm expecting the answer that will make a count on Stack Overflow without breaking terms and conditions.

Comment: You should fully understand the question and problem you are answering. If you learn something by using AI, you can write your own answer based on your knowledge regardless how you learned it. But you should be careful because AI can imagine things that are not correct and even code that works can have deficiencies. That is why it is critical that you really need to understand the problem well in order to answer. If your knowledge solely comes from AI, then I would advise you that you don't post answers based on that knowledge anyway even if you have written them on your own.

Comment: One of the answers you posted is clearly AI generated (even if you changed some parts) Moderators would detect such answer even without your admission.  Such answers are not acceptable. Please delete it yourself. The other answer you posted is rather low quality, because the user asking question haven't properly explained their problem, so you are just guessing.  It is best to avoid answering questions that are not clear.

Comment: @Dalija luckily OP caught on, lol: _"Did you just copy the title into chatgpt?"_

Answer (score 21):

What do you mean by "critical"? What is your experience? Why do you mention ChatGPT first and then your own logic, and not the other way around? How are you planning on recognizing ChatGPT getting things wrong?

All in all, the point of answering questions is that first and foremost you should be pretty sure that you understand the question and that it is unambiguous and clear and on-topic, and second that what you're posting is an actual answer to said question.

ChatGPT doesn't know any of that. It just rambles on based on what you enter. Therefore using it to answer questions asked here is not a good idea.

---

Can you explain where exactly you applied your own logic and modification here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514160/